# UITextView in UIScrollView with paging not scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have implemented a paging `UIScrollView` following this excellent tutorial:
http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/

The `UIScrollView` works like a charm with paging and all. Now, I want to add a `UITextView` to each of the pages. The `TextView` should have a fixed size to fit the frame but with scrolling content (if needed). I'm banging my head against the wall because no matter what I try I can't get the textview to scroll! In the main for-loop from the above tutorial I added the following code:

```
CGRect labelFrame;
UITextView *textView;

labelFrame.size.width = scrollView.frame.size.width-24;
labelFrame.size.height = scrollView.frame.size.height-48;
labelFrame.origin.x = 10;
labelFrame.origin.y = 40;

textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
textView.text = @"a very long text";

textView.editable = NO;
textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
textView.delegate = self;
textView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1, 1000); //this would make it scroll?
[subview addSubview:textView];
```

I've googled and tested a lot of things but the textview won't scroll. I tested the `delaysContentTouches` flag, I've locked scrolling directions but it does not change a thing.
In another project I tried to do the same and there I got it to scroll on the first page but not on the others?

I'm totally lost in space right, hope that anyone out there have the (probably simple) solution.

Here is a link to the complete project:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7312515/mycode.zip

Comment: I just pasted this exact code in Xcode, and the textview could scroll.

Comment: thanks for a quick answer. I think you have tested only the above code ? Because that will probably work. But if you try to use it in the mentioned tutorial (when it's placed into a sidescrolling UIScrollView with paging) it won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this and it works fine.

In your code, you are adding the text view to the `subview`. Instead, you should be adding it to the scroll view.

The subview does nothing, just provide the red color. You can send it to the back by calling

```
[self.scrollView bringSubviewToFront:textView];
```

PS: Don't forget to adjust the `x` of `labelFrame` to `subview.frame.size.width +10`. ;-)

Comment: Strange, that actually didn't work for me? I add the textView to the scrollview and set labelFrame to scrollView.frame.size.width*i +10 but no cigar. I read somewhere that the scrollview takes all the touch events and does not send them down to the textview, could that be the problem?

Comment: I've added a link to the complete project in my question for you to test.

Comment: I was thinking about the fact that it could have to do with the view hierarchy intercepting the clicks. You could check with `touchesBegan` calling `super` etc. but this will be quite some work. I think it has nothing to do with that. Check out my repo which works: [Repo](https://github.com/mundstein/UIScrollViewPagingTextView)

Comment: Thank you so much! After looking in you code I updated my code to completely skip the subview and addded directly to the scrollview instead and now it finally works!