# UITextView Paging not scrolling

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uitextview, paging

A question has been asked exactly the same previously, but I want someone to convert the code of the answer to Swift, as it is in objective-c. I also want to do the majority of this in storyboard, can SO users please help me?
[UITextView in UIScrollView with paging not scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874300/uitextview-in-uiscrollview-with-paging-not-scrolling)

If your lazy to look at the link, like we all are:

```
CGRect labelFrame;
UITextView *textView;

labelFrame.size.width = scrollView.frame.size.width-24;
labelFrame.size.height = scrollView.frame.size.height-48;
labelFrame.origin.x = 10;
labelFrame.origin.y = 40;

textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
textView.text = @"a very long text";

textView.editable = NO;
textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
textView.delegate = self;
textView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1, 1000); //this would make it scroll?
[subview addSubview:textView];
```

Also, the question's answer I don't completely understand what he's saying.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I completely understand your question, but if you want to enable scrolling in a UITexView from storyboard, drag and drop the UITextView from object library and select the "Scrolling Enabled" attribute for UITextField in attribute inspector.
[image: Select 'Scrolling Enabled']

Answer (score 0):

Delete 
`textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`
and paste

```
textView.isSelectable = false
textView.isEditable = false
```